# Matching/replacing cell data with hyperlinks from another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a lot of manual work and I tried finding relevant macros, but unfortunately could not find any.

Basically, my Excel sheet has 4 columns (A, B, C, D). I am left with data in columns A and B after doing a lot of screening on the current month's company filings (I remove certain marcaps above and below my range, I remove data not relevant to not my sector, etc.).

- Column A has the company name (upper case, lower case and sometimes combination)
- Column B has the date (I am doing by month now)

Once these 2 columns are ready, I run a web query from website, which downloads the entire month's filings with SEC with hyperlinks.

- Column C has the Company Name with HYPERLINKS (not necessarily same case formatting as in Col A)
- Column D has the Date (I am downloading monthly, so that will be the same month)

Column C has data that is much more than Col A; it has all the unwanted companies' hyperlinks too and there is no way that the search on that website can be more customized than to the extent it currently is.

Col D is much longer than Col B, because of more filings

e.g.:

```
Col A   Col B        Col C          Col D
                     (Hyperlinks)
Abc     3/1/2008     AAA            3/1/2008
BCD     3/1/2008     AAB            3/1/2008
BCD     3/2/2008     AAC            3/1/2008 
cDE     3/2/2008     ABC            3/1/2008
DeF     3/3/2008     ABE            3/1/2008
                     BCD            3/1/2008
                     ABC            3/2/2008
                     BCD            3/2/2008
                     CDE            3/2/2008
                     AAA            3/3/2008
                     AAF            3/3/2008
                     DEF            3/3/2008
```

I need the company in Col C to replace Col A with its Hyperlink, provided they are on the same date (Col B=Col D), irrespective of case (company names are unique).

The order of the companies in Col A and C are not same, even if I sort 'A-Z' for these columns, because of unwanted companies' data in Col C. C is a much longer column than A.

Each month has 1200 to 1500 filings and I am checking manually and replacing manually date-wise. I have to do this for 3 years, I am still in the same month for past 10 days. There is still more: I have to open each filing and read through and update the remarks column.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want AAA, AAB and AAC deleted from column C (together with the matching values in column D) and the remaining values in columns C and D moved up.  Further deletions from Column C and D as necessary.  The result sought is, for every row, columns A and C to identify the same company and for column B and D to be the same date.  You say column C contains hyperlinks; can you give more information about these hyperlinks?

Comment: I basically run a webquery from sec.gov that downloads the company's report, with the report information in that link. If I click that link it opens that document. I have to go thru these documents to understand what shareholder is writing abt the company.

Comment: Also, not necessarily C and D have to move up, the results can be extracted into the next columns (Eand F), not all company's retain same name, so I should have the master file I downloaded, to chk the new company names and do that 10% manually

Comment: Hi...is any answer possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code below does what you seek.

I created this worksheet to match your image:

[image: Before image]

The macro below changes the worksheet to:

[image]

Columns C and D are now redundent since every value in those columns has been moved to column F and G.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Meena ran the macro against her data but it did not match all the values that should have been matched.  She emailed me a copy of her data.  Having examined her data, I have made three changes to the macro below:

- Meena's worksheet has no heading row.  I use a constant to specify the first data row.  I have changed the value from 2 to 1.
- Many of the reference values have trailing spaces.  I have used TRIM() to remove those trailing spaces before the comparisons.
- The macro creates two new columns of data.  These were left at the default width so if the value was long, it would wrap and require several lines.  I have now added code to copy the the column widths from the source columns to the destination columns.

.

```
 Option Explicit
  ' If the columns have to be moved, update these constants
  ' and the code will change to match.
  Const ColRefCompany As Long = 1
  Const ColRefDate As Long = 2
  Const ColWebCompany As Long = 3
  Const ColWebDate As Long = 4
  Const ColSaveCompany As Long = 6
  Const ColSaveDate As Long = 7
  Const ColLastLoad As Long = 4
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 1        ' No header row
Sub CopyWebValuestoSaveColumns()

  Dim CellValue() As Variant
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowRefCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSave() As Long
  Dim RowSaveCrnt As Long
  Dim RowWebCrnt As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long

  ' Find the last cell with a value
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

   If Rng Is Nothing Then
     Call MsgBox("Sheet is empty", vbOKOnly)
     Exit Sub
   End If
   RowLast = Rng.Row
   ' Load all reference and web values to CellValue.  Searching an array
   ' is faster than searching the worksheet and hyperlinks are converted
   ' to their display values which gives an easier comparison.
   ' Note for arrays loaded from a worksheet, dimension one is for rows
   ' and dimension two is for columns.
   CellValue = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowLast, ColLastLoad)).Value

   ' RowSave() will record the position in the save columns of the values
   ' in the web columns.  Allow for one entry per row in web list.
   ReDim RowSave(1 To RowLast)

   RowRefCrnt = RowDataFirst

   ' Set web company names to lower case and remove leading and trailing
   ' spaces ready for matching
   For RowWebCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast
     CellValue(RowWebCrnt, ColWebCompany) = _
                               Trim(LCase(CellValue(RowWebCrnt, ColWebCompany)))
   Next

   Do While True
     If CellValue(RowRefCrnt, ColRefCompany) = "" Then
       ' Empty cell in reference company column.  Assume end of list
       Exit Do
     End If
     ' This loop makes no assumptions about the sequence of the
     ' Reference and Web lists.  If you know their sequences match or
     ' if you can sort the two pairs of columns, this loop could be
     ' made faster
     ' Set reference company name to lcase and remove leading and trailing
     ' spaces ready for matching
     CellValue(RowRefCrnt, ColRefCompany) = _
                              Trim(LCase(CellValue(RowRefCrnt, ColRefCompany)))

     For RowWebCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast
       If CellValue(RowRefCrnt, ColRefCompany) = _
                                      CellValue(RowWebCrnt, ColWebCompany) And _
          CellValue(RowRefCrnt, ColRefDate) = _
                                          CellValue(RowWebCrnt, ColWebDate) Then
         ' Reference and web values match.
         ' Record that the web values from row RowWebCrnt
         ' are to be copied to row RowRefCrnt
         RowSave(RowWebCrnt) = RowRefCrnt
         Exit For
       End If
     Next
     RowRefCrnt = RowRefCrnt + 1
   Loop
   RowSaveCrnt = RowRefCrnt     ' First row in save column that is available
                                ' for unused web values
   For RowWebCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast
     If RowSave(RowWebCrnt) = 0 Then
       ' The web values on this row has not been matched to reference values.
       ' Record these web values are to be moved to the next available row
       ' in the save columns
       RowSave(RowWebCrnt) = RowSaveCrnt
       RowSaveCrnt = RowSaveCrnt + 1
     End If
   Next

   .Columns(ColSaveCompany).ColumnWidth = .Columns(ColWebCompany).ColumnWidth
   .Columns(ColSaveDate).ColumnWidth = .Columns(ColWebDate).ColumnWidth

   ' Copy values from web columns to save columns
   For RowWebCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowLast
     .Range(.Cells(RowWebCrnt, ColWebCompany), _
            .Cells(RowWebCrnt, ColWebDate)).Copy _
                       Destination:=.Cells(RowSave(RowWebCrnt), ColSaveCompany)
   Next

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tony for this, but should I change all the cell values to lowercase?? This macro gives me approximately 1 or 2 results for each date, when there are actually more, that can be copied to the result columns!! Thanks again...this was definitely helpful...but I lack experience in VBA coding to customise!!

Comment: Hi Tony tried a lot to post my excel result sheet to show to you, but dint know how to do it. I tried reading the code and understood it, the logic is correct, but not sure why it is not applying to rest of the values.